# Delete query in MS Access throws error data type mismatch

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

What's wrong with my query below?

```
sqlquery = "DELETE FROM tblProductTransDetail WHERE (InvoiceNo) = @inv"

With sqlcommand
     .CommandText = sqlquery
     .Parameters.AddWithValue("@inv", Val(TextBoxNoNota.Text))
     .Connection = FormMain.conn
     .ExecuteNonQuery()
End With
```

also tried :

```
"DELETE FROM tblProductTransDetail WHERE InvoiceNo = @inv"
```

and some other but none worked.

My `InvoiceNo` is `number` type in database (MS Access 2016).

Comment: I don't think MS Access understands the `@inv` part. It seems like it just uses `{0}`. Give me a bit....

Comment: i use the @ all over my code, especially in insert and select queries and worked well, why delete query cannot understand it ?

Comment: If `InvoiceNo` is an integer, you are passing a double.  AddWithValue is a bad idea *because* you are requiring the DB provide to guess at the data types.  The apparent default form instance is an equally bad idea

Comment: Do you have a relationship between `tblProductTransDetail` and something else (like `tblProductTransHeader`)?

Comment: As @Plutonix suggests, what happens when you try this `
                .Parameters.Add("@inv", OleDBType.Integer).value = Val(TextBoxNoNota.Text)` ?

Comment: @Plutonix  i tried to pass a direct number (instead of variable or textbox) and stil not work

Comment: usually, i go with `.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inv", TextBoxNoNota.Text )` in insert,update or select query and it actually worked. only delete query give me error

Comment: I have no idea what a "direct number" is.  `Val` however always returns a double which is not an integer and therefore a data type mismatch.  If the source is a TextBox, the user inputs a value?  Then you should use TryParse.

Comment: what i meant with direct number is like `.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inv", 10)`

Comment: Number is generic and sorta misleading.  Data types can be integer, decimal, double, etc - in the designer, what does it have for "field size"?

Comment: @JimmySmith its long integer, As i have stated before that i have been working with this table so many times, inserting it, updating it, doing joined query, no problem so far. today i am planning to add new method to delete. and here i am stuck with it. something i never expected to be problem because other queries just doing great till now.

Comment: @Goofy_Phie ahhhh well then lets do another test, change `@inv` to `?` .  To my knowledge, Access doesn't support named parameters, so I've got ? in my code.  [This is how it works per Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: "doesnt support named parameters" just means you cannot reference them by name - you need to add values in the exact same order, but that will not result in a data type mismatch error.  If the data type is long, pass a long, not an integer, not a double.

Comment: I cannot recall the specifics, but I know I started using ? in my Access queries for a reason... Again, per Microsoft, "The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the question mark (?) placeholder must be used."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

however i can make it run properly by using standard delete query without parameter

```
sqlquery = "DELETE FROM tblProductTransDetail WHERE InvoiceNo = " & cleansql(TextBoxNoNota.Text)
```

Note: cleansql is my function to clean text and prevent injection.

Comment: What happens when you use `.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inv", CLng(TextBoxNoNota.Text))`  While I know the parameters can be tricky, this code is subject to a SQL injection attack.

Comment: I realize that. But in my case my TextBoxNoNota is disabled for user input. Its generated by my other code. If you follow from earlier comment, you can read how i     tried to make my parameterized query worked. But unfortunately this is the only way working for now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please give this a shot instead?  Also assuming you have an import to System.Data.OleDb at the top.

The Convert.ToInt32 makes the text a integer (assuming its a number and not text).  The invParam is enforced to have a data type of integer.

```
sqlquery = "DELETE FROM tblProductTransDetail WHERE (InvoiceNo) = ?"

With sqlcommand
     .CommandText = sqlquery
     Dim invParam as new OleDbParameter("InvoiceNo", OleDbType.Integer)
     invParam.Value = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxNoNota.Text)
     .Parameters.Add(invParam)
     .Connection = FormMain.conn
     .ExecuteNonQuery()
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You used the SQL query not the MS ACCESS query.

You should try this

```
sqlquery = "DELETE  * FROM tblProductTransDetail WHERE (InvoiceNo) = @inv"
```

Delete query in SQL doesn't have *, But in Access has an * in delete query

Comment: also i think the error is = @inv. Please specify like this

Where InVoiceNo = '"& txtInv.Text & "'